# ChromeHeadless was not killed in 2000ms

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, google-chrome-headless

I have been hitting my head on this for a week now and no leads for till now.

ChromeHeadless was not killed in 2000 ms, sending SIGKILL.
when i am trying to run the tests , it starts and complete all the test but at the end throws error.
Test are running fine and i also tried with firefoxHeadless as well but of no use for me.

tried with different set of versions but didn't work.

Comment: Any luck? I've been hitting this issue as well. I did find this, https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher/issues/180; but it address failures that occur at the beginning of tests (which I fixed by setting singleRun to true).

Comment: I had the same issue with high load on the build agent. I wonder, if it is possible to increase the 2 second timeout somehow.

Comment: have anyone found the solutions?
I had the same issue.
Thank you

Comment: I had this issue when the headless driver was corrupt / uninstalled on the machine I was trying to access the driver. Re-install worked for me